# Anchor tags disappearing inside an expanding DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

#### HTML:

```
 <li>
   <a href="images/bg/tommag4.png">Plan Search</a>
   <div class="ac_subitem">
     <span class="ac_close"></span>
     <h2 style="border-bottom:1px #989898 dotted; Margin:0 20px;">Advanced Plan Search</h2>
     <a href="#" id="testanchor">TEST LINK</a>
     <li>Feature Under Construction</li>
   </div>
 </li>
```

#### CSS:

```
.ac_subitem {
    width:1000px;
    height:0px; /* animate to 400px */
    top:50%;
    right:0px;
    margin-top:0px; /* animate to -200px */
    position:fixed;
    z-index:99;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:transparent url(../images/bg_menu.png) repeat top left;
}
```

Basically, I have a navigation set up via `<ul></ul>` each `<li>` contains an expandable `<div>`. What I am trying to do is add anchor tags to external links within these `<div>`s however the text/image used will not show up, the anchor is there and clickable but the contact itself will not appear, thus leaving me with a clickable blank space. any ideas?

**Note:** I do have the JS used to perform these actions, but it is quite lengthy. If necessary I can post that as well. thanks for your time in advanced!

**Edit:** Here is the fiddle for whole code used http://jsfiddle.net/8smk6mhs/. It doesn't seem to load properly in jsFiddle, however everything is loading fine using provided code in Dreamweaver6 links to jQuery and http://yourjavascript.com/0073145129/center-menu.js load it properly. Also a link to the completed template purchased for this project in comments.

**Edit2:** Have since gone through, validated, cleaned up the code. I have been trying to work through this problem for days now, and cannot grasp why this is happening. the fact that the anchor is active and works but Just cannot properly display contents of anchor is what really confuses me.

*****I've updated the Fiddle.

Comment: Would be a lot more useful if there was a link to someting like jsfiddle with all the required code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: template link for visual aid. http://valleyforgetemplate.info/index.html

Comment: Dylan, get your code, copy it in Validator and start debugging it, you have LOTS of errors, unclosed tags, stray elements and such. Once you do that, it will probably work